# How much tax credit I get for monthly metropass in toronto

Tags: taxes, canada, ontario

I pay for my own public transit monthly pass in Toronto. I am not sure how much of the amount I pay is tax deductible?

http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/ddctns/lns360-390/364/rtrn-eng.html

What amount should I put on my tax return form? The full amount that I paid over the year?

Answer (score 1):

Monthly transit passes qualify for a tax credit.

The instructions tell you to enter all your **privately** paid transit pass costs, if any, (the total), on line 364.

In addition, if your **employer paid** the transit passes for all or part of the year, that payment will be entered on your T-4 from your employer;  you (or tax software will include this on Line 364.

The amount is added to other amounts, and qualifies for a 15% tax credit.

Answer (score 0):

None of the amount you paid for public transit passes is tax-deductible, because it does not change your net income.

However there is a non-refundable federal tax credit at 15%. This means it can reduce your taxes payable, but cannot bring your taxes owed into negative territory.

Let's illustrate with two artificial examples for one tax year:

1. Income: $30 000.
   Transit pass amount: $1 000.
   Gross federal tax: $2 000.
   Tax credit: $150.
   Federal tax owed: $2000 − $150 = $1 850.
2. Income: $5 000.
   Transit pass amount: $1 000.
   Gross federal tax: $0.
   Tax credit: $150.
   Federal tax owed: $0 − $150 = −$150, but actually capped at $0 because the credit is non-refundable.